# Error in Vue3 - Argument of type 'typeof import("../dist/vue")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PublicAPIComponent'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I install vue using the cli v4.4.1.

After that I run this command to update to Vue3: `vue add vue-next` .

And when I open `main.ts` I get typescript error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof import("c:/../vue-app/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PublicAPIComponent'.
```

What I need to do to solve this error?

[image]

Comment: Same here, can't serve the application because of this

Comment: workaround: `createApp(app as any)`.  Vue team release the vue3 but without any effort we find a problem :(

Answer (score 31):

I solved the issue by updating the definition file for *.vue modules in `src/shims-vue.d.ts` with the following:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import { defineComponent } from "vue";
  const component: ReturnType<typeof defineComponent>;
  export default component;
}
```

source: https://dev.to/lmillucci/building-a-vue-3-component-with-typescript-4pge

Comment: Didn't work for me. So I have to use workaround, suggested by Jon Sud at the comments to original post: `createApp(app as any)`.

Comment: Not working either and casting as `any` defeats the purpose of using ts in the first place